# Azure service bus "send" throws Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I'm not sure what has changed but all of a sudden I get an "InvalidOperationException - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object". My code has definitely worked previously and I can't remember changing anything.

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.3

I tried some very basic code and still get the same error:

```
var bus = new QueueClient("Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=Manage;SharedAccessKey=xxx", "service-event");
await bus.SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"test\":\"hi\"}")));
```

Any ideas?

Edit stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.<OnSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.<SendAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TwitchEventAdapter.EventHandler.<SendEvent>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\...\EventHandler.cs:line 66
```

Comment: Can you please post the 'full' stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I updated the post with a stacktrace @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT

Comment: sorry I meant also the full exception (not only stacktrace)  like detailed message and innerexception (if any).

Comment: There is no inner exception and "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." is the full message I'm afraid

Comment: I am afraid I could not reproduce with the code snippet you shared trying with different scenario. I might need to look at more holistic view of your application code. Also, did you check if the queue is healthy? You can test it by sending message via some different client like [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer)

Comment: I tried connecting with Service Bus Explorer and it sent/received messages just fine. I created a brand new project which has the same problem for me and pushed it here: https://github.com/Anton0123/ServiceBusErrorDemo

Comment: Solved it by changing the target framework to something other than .NET 5.0. Thank you for your help anyways @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT

Comment: Glad about that. Yeah .net 5 is still in preview. So all the older SDKs might not 
 be yet compatible. However if you use the newer SB SDK  [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) (which is also still in preview) with .net 5, you would not encounter this.

Comment: it still happens in the release version of net 5 as of today

Answer (score 32):

If you're using .Net 5.0 RC2, then installing [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus version 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/5.0.0) should solve the problem.

Comment: Works for me with .NET 6 as well. Thanks!

Comment: updated to the latest Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and that worked! thank you

Comment: this one solved my issue, I was using .Net6 and the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus was set to version 4.1.2, changing to version 5.2.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Changing project version from .NET 5.0 to .NET core 3.1 solved the problem.

Comment: This comment has solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Downgrading .NET isn't really a good suggestion imho

Comment: I would consider this temporary at best. Sometimes we are trying to upgrade and don't want to downgrade.